# Scale limit for matrix transform for a Microsoft Surface application

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense, rendertransform

I've developed a surface application in which users are able to pull from a menu a movie and drag it on the main canvas. I've created a user control to host the movie and I implemented Affine2dManipulation in order to allow the users to rotate, scale and move the control on the main canvas.
The problem is that i want to set a scale limit for control. The RenderTransform is handled by a MatrixTransform.

If anyone has any ideeas on how to limit the scaletransform for the matrix please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason why you aren't using ScatterView/ScatterViewItem? Because those controls are meant to give you the exact behavior you explained here.